# Strange black artifacts in ambient occlusion map

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, texture-baking

I've been trying to create an AO map for my dragon model. However, I've been struggling with this one quite long time already as the baking process takes quite much time aswell. I searched a solution for my problem in the Internet, but it seems I can' t find solution for my problem.

That's why I'm here to ask your help. Maybe you could tell me what I'm doing wrong. The model part I'm trying to bake AO map from is here and the AO map with artifacts is also provided below.

I also don' t know whether I should bake my AO map with cycles render engine or Blender render engine. What is the difference?

**THE OBJECT I'M BAKING AO MAP FROM**

[image]

**THE AO MAP**

[image]

**THE AO BAKING OPTIONS OF MY CYCLES RENDER**
[image]

Comment: Try to increase *Margin* and check for double vertices / faces in model. It seems that something is overlapping. Keep in mind that amount of render samples will also affect on AO map quality (hence the more or less visible noise of AO).

Comment: The margin seems not to be the problem at the moment as the purpose of margin is to cover the islands of the UV map properly so the edges of the UV islands wouldn' t be unbaked. When I increase the margin, I'm afraid some islands will apparently collide... Hmm.. I didn' t understand the "check for double vertices/faces in model" part. I have placed my UV islands so they wouldn' t overlap, but I don' t know, they might somehow overlap..

Comment: By double faces in model I meant possible overlapping geometry in mesh, not in UV map. Try maybe baking into completely new image (not rewriting), this is very unlikely to help but recently I did have a problem with that. And for baking AO Lightmap Pack is also rather useful option instead of unwrap with seams.

Comment: Did you set a material on it ? It may come from it.

Comment: I had the default grey material for my mesh. About the suggestsions, Mr Zak, I will try your suggestions. Although.... I spent soo much time creating nice UV map (placing the UV islands on my own)...

Comment: I support @MrZak answer. I am shure you have two overlapping meshes in the scene. Be shure the hidden mesh will not be rendered, too. Disable the render option for the hidden object in the outliner.